# Generating functions (with symbol method) of special partitions of natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions, analytic-combinatorics

I want to show that the generating function of the number of partitions where every summand appears at most twice of every natural number n equals the number of paritions of n into summands which are not divisible by 3.

I know that for the partitions $\mathcal{\tilde{P}}$ where every summand appears at most once it holds that:

$\tilde{\mathcal{P}} = (\epsilon + 1)\times (\epsilon + 2) \times (\epsilon + 3) \times \dotsc$ and therefore $P(z) = (1+z)(1+z^2)(1+z^3) + \dotsc$.

So now I'm wondering if the partitions $\mathcal{P}$ where every summand appears at motst twice is described as

1) $\mathcal{P} = (\{\epsilon\} + \{1\} + \{1,1\})\times (\{\epsilon\} + \{2\} + \{2,2\}) \times (\{\epsilon\} + \{3\} + \{3,3\}) \times \dotsc$ and therefore corresponds with

1a)
$P(z) = (1+z+2z)(1+z^2+2z^2)+(1+z^3+2z^3) \dotsc$ or with

1b) 
$P(z) = (1+ z + z)(1+ z^2 + z^4)(1+z^3+z^6)\dotsc$

or if the description is

2) $\mathcal{P} = (\epsilon + 1)\times(\epsilon + 1) \times (\epsilon + 2) \times (\epsilon + 2) \times \dotsc$ and therefore corresponds with

$P(z) = (1+z)^2(1+z^2)^2(1+z^3)^2\dotsc$?

The second partition, the one into parts that are not divisible by 3, I think the description is:

$\mathcal{P}^{\ast} = SEQ(1) \times SEQ(2) \times SEQ(4) \times \dotsc$

and therefore $P^{\ast}(z) = \frac{1}{1-z}\frac{1}{1-z^2}\frac{1}{1-z^4}\frac{1}{1-z^5}\dotsc$.

So is any of the options described in 1) correct, and if so, which one or why not, and is 2) correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GF of the partitions where every summand appears at most twice is 
$$f(x)=(1+x+x^2)(1+x^2+x^4)\cdot\ldots = \prod_{k\geq 1}(1+x^k+x^{2k})$$
while the GF of the partitions into summands which are not divisible by 3 is 
$$ g(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^4}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^5}\cdot\ldots = \prod_{\substack{k\geq 1\\3\nmid k}}\frac{1}{1-x^k}. $$
It is not difficult to check that $f(x)=g(x)$. Indeed
$$ f(x)=\prod_{k\geq 1}\frac{1-x^{3k}}{1-x^k} = \prod_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{1-x^k}\prod_{k\geq 1}(1-x^{3k}) = \prod_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{1-x^n}\prod_{\substack{n\geq 1\\ 3\mid n}}(1-x^n) = g(x).$$

Comment: Thanks for answering! Can you please explain to me why it's not what I suggested in 1a) and 2)?

Comment: @Studentu: in 1a) you are counting the partitions with a duplicated summand incorrectly. For instance, $1+2+2+3$ is counted twice. In 2) you are incorrectly counting the partitions with an isolated summand. For instance, $1+2+3$ is counted eight times.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get your explanation for 1a). 
2) I've understood, I guess. It's because the way I've described it there, there would be two parts for taking out 1 (the first and second factor), then two parts for taking out 2 (the 3rd and 4th factor) and so on, right? But what do you mean by "isolated summand"?

Comment: With multiplicity $1$. The GF outlined in your point 2) is $(1+2x+x^2)(1+2x^2+x^4)(1+2x^3+x^6)\cdot\ldots$, so a partition with a single $1$, a single $2$ and a single $3$ is counted $8=2\cdot 2\cdot 2$ times, not just one.

Comment: Ah okay, that's clear to me now, thank you! 
And how about 1a)? Could you be more precise regarding it, too, please?

Comment: @Studentu: in 1a) you should have considered that $\{1,1\}$ has weight $2$, and write $(1+z+z^2)$ instead of $(1+z+2z)$; $(1+z^2+z^4)$ instead of $(1+z^2+2z^2)$ etcetera.

Comment: Oh and $(1+z+2z)$ would mean that we choose between an element of weight 0 and 3 elements of weight 1?

Comment: @Studentu: yes, exactly.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help, I appreciate that! :)